# How do I deploy a compiled database that no one can see/view source script but can execute it

Tags: sql, sql-server, security

I developed an application that used SQL Server database 2017. I wrote most of the business logic in stored procedures, triggers & UDF. Now at the time of Go-Live, I want to deploy a compiled database on a client-server machine so no one can view or change scripts.

I can manage this from the SQL Security, access rights, etc. but actually, the Client network administrator has all the credentials and rights of the database and I do not want anyone to view/change the script even the administrator.

can I deploy a compiled database on a client-server instead of a regular one so no one can view/change scripts but can execute them Similarly like EXE file users can execute it but cannot view/change the code?

Does Microsoft SQL Server provide a solution on this or any workaround?

please suggest thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way of doing this. You can create the modules `WITH ENCRYPTION` but that is easily undone by anyone with sufficient permissions and access to Google

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't even apply to .exe files.